# Understanding what the Min/Max commands in QGIS raster calculator do?

Tags: qgis, raster-calculator

I understand the examples on the official QGIS page showing bracketed expressions result in 0 or 1 and those integers can be scaled or values added, but I clearly do not understand how to use the MIN and MAX values and every attempt crashes.

I want to "clip" grid values by setting grid values < 1% of the value to that 1% value. I also want to do the same with those above 99%.

I try

```
(grid < (MAX (grid) - MIN(grid) /100) ) * (MAX (grid) - MIN(grid) / 100)
```

but this crashes QGIS.

Is this possible? If other commands change every cell, what are MIN and MAX actually doing?

QGIS Raster Calculator page: [https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_raster/raster_calculator.html](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_raster/raster_analysis.html#raster-calculator)

Comment: Could you add a link to the documentation that you are referring to? Are you sure that you are not deviding by zero?

Comment: Added link to QGIS page

Comment: On that page I can see Min and Max only in MinX/MaxX, MinY, MaxY which mean the min/max easting-northing coordinates of the image. Is your link correct?

Comment: OK, got the latest QGIS Raster Calculator link now. As an aside, I am looking at ArcGIS at work and there is no Min or Max in it's Raster Calculator to compare with.